# Spring Security: аутентификация с пользовательской формы входа

Tags: jsp, spring-security

Здравствуйте! Разбираюсь со Spring Security, и в процессе появилась некая проблема, которую уже долго не могу победить. Есть небольшое веб-приложение, к которому требовалось прикрутить аутентификацию посредством Spring Security. Данные о пользователях хранятся в одной-единственной таблице БД (PostrgeSQL). В общем и целом задачу решил: если оставлять стандартную форму для входа Spring Security, то всё работает так, как нужно. Но если подсунуть свою собственную форму, поправив при этом конфигурацию безопасности, запрос к БД не возвращает значений (т.е. не находит в базе нужного пользователя). При этом authentification-provider во всех случаях остаётся один и тот же. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где копать.

Файл security-config.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.2.xsd">

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <form-login login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"

                default-target-url="/welcome"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout"  />
    <csrf/>
</http>

<beans:bean id="userDetailsServiceImpl" class="my.learning.payment.system.login.UserDetailsServiceImpl" />

<authentication-manager >
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsServiceImpl"/>
</authentication-manager>
```

Моя форма для аутентификации (да, IDEA помечает красным url /j_spring_security_check и говорит, что не может его зарезолвить):

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
```

Login page

```
<form action = "<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check' />" method="post">
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="j_username" placeholder="Enter phone number" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="password" name="j_password" placeholder="Enter your password" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
</form>
<form>
    <div>
        If you haven't any account please <a href="/register">register here</a>.
    </div>
</form>
```

Поставщик данных для аутентификации (AccountRepository - интерфейс, расширяющий JpaRepository)

```
import my.learning.payment.system.dao.AccountRepository;
import my.learning.payment.system.domain.Account;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private AccountRepository accountRepository;

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    Account account = accountRepository.findByPhone(s);
    if(account==null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Unknown account");
    }

    Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();
    grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(account.getRole()));

    return new User(account.getPhone(), account.getPassword(), grantedAuthorities);
}
```

}

В том виде, в каком всё представлено здесь, всё работает (вызывается стандартная спринговая форма, всё находится и аутентифициреутся). Но если я добавлю в конфиг строчку login-page="/login" (по этому адресу происходит вызов моей страницы авторизации), то по нажатию кнопки "Login" ничего не авторизуется. При этом стектрейс красивый: никаких исключений нет, ошибок тоже, просто запрос не находит в базе того, что надо (а оно там, разумеется есть).

Буду благодарен за любой совет!

Comment: Столкнулся с такой же проблеммой. "Свои значения" это какие? Я заменил теги на стандартные username и password, но всё равно не работает..

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена. Причина была в том, что я в тэгах input для ввода логина и пароля в качестве имён прописал стандартные спринговские значения j_username и j_password соответственно. Заменил эти значения на свои - и всё заработало.